# Doctrine QueryBuilder : Uncaught exception

Tags: php, codeigniter, doctrine

```
$qb = $this->doctrine->em->createQueryBuilder()                
            ->from('User','u')
            ->select('count(u.name)')
            ->where('u.name = :name')
            ->setParameter('name', $user->getUsername());
```

When I execute `$qb->getQuery()->getResult()`,
 I get this error:

> Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Doctrine\ORM\Query\QueryException' with message 'SELECT count(u.name) FROM User u WHERE u.name = :name' in /var/www/darkfrog/application/libraries/Doctrine/ORM/Query/QueryException.php:39Stack trace:
>
> `#0` /var/www/darkfrog/application/libraries/Doctrine/ORM/Query/Parser.php(429): Doctrine\ORM\Query\QueryException::dqlError('SELECT count(u....')
>
> `#1` /var/www/darkfrog/application/libraries/Doctrine/ORM/Query/Parser.php(854): Doctrine\ORM\Query\Parser->semanticalError('Class 'User' is...', Array)
>
> `#2` /var/www/darkfrog/application/libraries/Doctrine/ORM/Query/Parser.php(1529): Doctrine\ORM\Query\Parser->AbstractSchemaName()
>
> `#3` /var/www/darkfrog/application/libraries/Doctrine/ORM/Query/Parser.php(1426): Doctrine\ORM\Query\Parser->RangeVariableDeclaration()
>
> `#4` /var/www/darkfrog/application/libraries/Doctrine/ORM/Query/Parser.php(1168): Doctrine\ORM\Query\Parser->IdentificationVariableDeclaration()
>
> `#5` /var/www/darkfrog/application/libraries/Doctrine/ORM/Query/Parser.php(757): Doctrine\ORM\Query\Pars in /var/www/darkfrog/application/libraries/Doctrine/ORM/Query/QueryException.php on line 49

Answer (score 1):

the following code works great, just add "Entities\" in the clause from.

```
$qb = $this->doctrine->em->createQueryBuilder()
            ->select($this->doctrine->em->createQueryBuilder()->expr()->count('u.username'))
            ->from('Entities\User','u')
            ->where('u.username = :username')
            ->setParameter('username', $user->getUsername());
var_dump($qb->getQuery()->getResult());
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a User::class to define the entity name.

```
$qb = $this->doctrine->em->createQueryBuilder()                
            ->from(User::class,'u')
            ->select('count(u.name)')
            ->where('u.name = :name')
            ->setParameter('name', $user->getUsername());
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$qb->$this->doctrine->em->createQueryBuilder()
    ->select($qb->expr()->count('u.name'))
    ->from('User','u')
    ->where('u.name = :name')
    ->setParameter('name', $user->getUsername());
```

Comment: Thank you for your help, but I have the same error with your code.

Comment: what if you do `$qb->getDql()` instead of `getQuery()` to debug?

Comment: I have the next query : SELECT COUNT(u.name) FROM User u WHERE u.name = :name

Comment: The Query looks good, i'm thinking maybe it's something else. Does this output true `var_dump(is_string($user->getUsername()))` ?

Comment: $user->getUsername is a string. I have generated mappings and entites with reverse engineering from existing database. The files generated are may be false.

Comment: You can generate a schema in an empty database with the entities you have and then compare the differences with your current database. Normally it's doctrine:schema:update --force to put the tables in the database, but check Doctrine SchemaTools to be sure.

Comment: May be I have found my solution here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16720816/doctrine-querybuilder-returns-queryexception